# How do I populate a list of Images from a directory?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, list

trying to load in a bunch of images into a list from a directory...my code is below.

```
        string directory = @".\card_images\";
        List<Image> HandCards = new List<Image>();
foreach (string myFile in 
         Directory.GetFiles(directory,"*.png",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            HandCards.Add(myFile);
        }
```

This of course doesn't work because a string can't be converted to an Image, on the other hand if I try to make myFile into Image then Directory.GetFiles doesn't work either, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string directory = @".\card_images\";
List<Image> HandCards = new List<Image>();
foreach (string myFile in
          Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Image image = new Image();
    BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
    source.BeginInit();
    source.UriSource = new Uri(myFile, UriKind.Relative);
    source.EndInit();
    image.Source = source;

    HandCards.Add(image);
}
```

Comment: Have a way to do the same using Xamarin on a Mac?

Answer (score 6):

A cute one liner:

```
var handCards = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.png", 
                                   SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Select(Image.FromFile).ToList();
```

Comment: Very nice solution! I'll try this one if I run into hangups with the previous answer :).

Comment: It basecially does the exact same thing, except he initializes an image and then fills it with the file instead of just initializing it with the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)

Eg:

```
string directory = @".\card_images\";
List<Image> HandCards = new List<Image>();
foreach (string myFile in Directory.GetFiles(directory,"*.png",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    HandCards.Add(Image.FromFile(myFile));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) (read this) the `HandCards` collection and use an [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) to [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) the strings to an `Image`.

e.g.

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HandCards}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```